# Splitting a 'mixed' dirty branch into multiple clean branches

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I had a bad git workflow for a while -- I made changes regarding both subject A, subject B and subject C in the same `dirtybranch`, and in fact also in intermixed commits.

I want to clear this up, so that I have a clean `branchA`, `branchB` and `branchC` for each of these, so that I can later make separate merge requests for upstream.

I have already created branchA, used `git cherry-pick --no-commit master..dirtybranch` and then simply manually removed the changes regarding subjectB and C. This works although it is inelegant, and I could do the same for subjects B and C although it is looking to be more involved (because they are mixed up in the code more closely).

Therefore my question is:

- Is there a more elegant (ie. easier) way to do this, especially when you need to go through a file line by line to pick the changes you want to keep (gui?)? I know of eg. meld or kdiff but I am not sure how to apply them here.
- As I have already 'picked out' changes for subject A into `branchA`, is there a way to cherry-pick the changes from `dirtybranch` into eg. `branchB` "except for" the changes I already put into `branchA`? (and likewise, `dirtybranch`->`branchC` "except for" `branchA` and `branchB`)

Comment: Are you looking for an interactive rebase?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't think interactive rebase will fit this purpose. It would be similar to cherry-pick --no-commit except it seems very commit-oriented. This will not work for me, unfortunately, since I did not cleanly put changes regarding each subject into separate commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have already created branchA, used git cherry-pick --no-commit master..dirtybranch and then simply manually removed the changes regarding subjectB and C.

A similar approach would be `git reset` back to the point where `dirtybrach` branched off from `master`. There, you can create a new `branchA`, keeping all your changes unstaged and uncommitted. I usually do this if I have mixed up my commits and want to restructure the changes into new commits.

To separate the changes into different branches, you could find and commit all changes for `branchA`, stash the rest, go back to master, create `branchB`, apply the stash (giving you all changess from `dirtybranach` except those from `branchA`), find and commit the changes for `branchB`, and the whole thing again for `branchC`.

That resolves your second point. As for a GUI to make this whole thing as easy as possible, I can only recommend [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/), which has a pretty comfortable way to select the hunks or even single lines of a file you want to stage.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference `git add -p` or `git add -i` selectively stages changes (I had to look this up).